# Splitting strings into 2 columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, procedure

I am trying to write SQL statement or simple procedure for the below.
There is column name: `department_name` that contains the following string characters:

```
First Name&Second Name [W]
```

I need to split two things :
`First Name&Second Name` in one column called `department_name` and `[W]` in the second column  called `department_code`.

I need to do it for hundreds of rows.
How would the procedure or sql statement look in this case?
Length of the strings and number of words in department_name differs..

Comment: If the department_code is shown as [104] do you want the second column to show **[104]** (with the square brackets) or just **104**?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRIM( SUBSTR( department_name, 1, INSTR( department_name, '[' ) - 1 ) )
         AS department_name,
       SUBSTR( department_name, INSTR( department_name, '[' ) )
         AS department_code
FROM   your_table;
```

or

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( department_name, '(.*?)\s*(\[.*?\])', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS department_name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( department_name, '(.*?)\s*(\[.*?\])', 1, 1, NULL, 2 )
         AS department_code
FROM   your_table;
```

or, if you don't want the brackets in the department code then:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( department_name, '(.*?)\s*\[(.*?)\]', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS department_name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( department_name, '(.*?)\s*\[(.*?)\]', 1, 1, NULL, 2 )
         AS department_code
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Thx it is very useful.

Comment: @m4ndy If an answer has solved your problem then you can mark it as accepted (green check mark below the voting buttons) which will indicate that the question is closed. If it has not solved your problem then you can add a comment with the outstanding issues and/or edit your question.